OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin: How to generate Tags and Servers from OpenAPI YAML into SpringDocConfiguration?
Given the following OpenAPI YAML extract ...
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: Customer API
  description: |
    Through this API, the platform can communicate with the application which manages customer contracts
  version: 0.5.0
  license:
    name: Company license
    url: https://www.company.com/license
  contact:
    email: john.doe@company.com
    name: John Doe
    url: https://www.company.com/contact
servers:
  - url: https://application-test.company.com
    description: Test Environment
  - url: https://application-uat.company.com
    description: User Acceptance Environment
  - url: https://application.company.com
    description: Production Environment
tags:
  - name: input
    description: Actions related to sending and retrieving of customer contracts
  - name: output
    description: Actions related to getting customer contracts
paths:
  ...


... I use the OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin to invoke the spring generator
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.8.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>
                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/app-api.yaml
                </inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <apiPackage>com.company.application.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.company.application.api.model</modelPackage>
                <supportingFilesToGenerate>
                    ApiUtil.java,SpringDocConfiguration.java
                </supportingFilesToGenerate>
                <configOptions>
                    <skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>true</skipIfSpecIsUnchanged>
                    <useSpringBoot3>true</useSpringBoot3>
                    <generateBuilders>true</generateBuilders>
                    <annotationLibrary>swagger2</annotationLibrary>
                </configOptions>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

... in order to generate the corresponding SpringDocConfiguration:
@Configuration
public class SpringDocConfiguration {

  @Bean(name = "org.openapitools.configuration.SpringDocConfiguration.apiInfo")
  OpenAPI apiInfo() {
    return new OpenAPI()
        .info(
          new Info()
            .title("Customer API")
            .description("Through this API, the platform can communicate with the application which manages customer contracts")
            .contact(
              new Contact()
                .name("John Doe")
                .url("https://www.company.com/contact")
                .email("john.doe@company.com")
              )
              .license(
                new License()
                  .name("Company license")
                  .url("https://www.company.com/license")
              )
              .version("0.5.0")
            )
            .servers(...) // missing
            .tags(...) // missing
      ;
  }
}

Notice that while all info has been generated correctly, the servers and tags are missing.
I found a resolved Github PR that suggests this (at least servers) has been implemented, but it is somehow not applied.
I could not find a proper configuration parameter in the Spring Generator documentation to enable it either.
Therefore, how can I generate server en tag information using the OpenAPI Generator Maven Plugin into SpringDocConfiguration or any other file? Is it even possible? Is it a matter of configuration or of missing dependencies?

In the code as I can see servers and tags are in the info but in yaml servers and tags are on the same level. Try to put spaces before servers and tags to make them in info block:
info:
 title:
 ...
 servers:
 tags: 


Nice observation, but indenting tags and servers into info makes the Yaml file invalid:
[ERROR] 
org.openapitools.codegen.SpecValidationException: There were issues with the specification. The option can be disabled via validateSpec (Maven/Gradle) or --skip-validate-spec (CLI).
| Error count: 2, Warning count: 0
Errors:
-attribute info.tags is unexpected
-attribute info.servers is unexpected
